# Search by more than one tag at once (OR)

Tags: feature-request

*My feature-request:*  **There should be a way to search for multiple tags at once** (**A OR B**, rather than **A AND B**) from the GUI

*Reason:* When looking for interesting questions asked while I was gone, I will follow this procedure:

1. Click on *newest*
2. Click on one of my *interesting tags*
3. Open a number of links, scrolling down until I find one that I've seen before
4. Click on the next *interesting tag*
5. Open a number of links, scrolling down until I find one that I've seen before
6. ...

Not only do I have to try to remember which questions I've seen before, but some of them have *two* of my *interesting tags*, so that something I've *"seen before"* I actually first saw a minute or two ago.

**[Edit]** A simple thing would be make the *"Interesting Tags"* header link to a page that displays all posts that have one of your interesting tags.

Answer (score 2):

You could manually construct your url.

This is the one I use:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=perl~+~regex~+pcre+or+language-agnostic+or+parse+or+rosetta-stone+or+code-golf&sort=active

Comment: Then I'd like there to be a way of saving/editing these groups of tags on the site, rather than having to save a bunch of bookmarks and edit them manually whenever I wanted to change a tag-grouping.

Comment: @BlueRaja Better late than never: Instead of saving a bunch of bookmarks, you could create a URL builder script in something like AutoKey. It could be as simple as multiple phrases, one for each desired predicate, or as fancy as a loop with a menu for sequentially adding predicates.